# How to use typescript browser types in blazor app?

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, blazor, typescript-typings

I was experimenting around with typescript in blazor and wanted to access some data from the browser (doesn't matter what exactly, this is a general problem).

I'm not very experienced with typescript (only written a bit of javascript before), but I'm kinda good at C# so I decided to try and use it. I know that typescript unlike javascript has types, so what I was wondering is whether there are any types defined in typescript that I could use in my program?

I found this in the Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

`document` has a lot of properties, so I guess there is some sort of datatype defining such a document in typescript right? I though that was the whole point of the language (these typings).

When I write document in my program nothing really happens, the suggestions menu is pretty much empty (unlike in C# where it would tell me what I have to import or whatever etc.).

So my question is, are there types defined in typescript for these web-objects and how can I use them in blazor (maybe 3-rd party libraries I need to import)?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript only defines basic types like boolean, string, number, enum, etc. It is a super-set of javascript so you can code against the same Document Object Model you normally would in javascript. All javascript is also valid Typescript.

If you are not getting code completion then it is environmental, not an issue with the Typescript language.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Still, I'm trying to get the types for the browser (you can see them in the Mozilla documentation I linked) no matter where they come from, I stated that I would also be OK with a 3rd party library if there aren't any of these types in typescript directly.

Comment: @looat What I'm saying is that the "types for the browser" (DOM) should be available in intellisense/code completion. I never have a problem with it, your IDE/project may just not be setup for it.

Comment: ahh got you. but my question still stands unanswered then. I ask specifically how I can get those types in blazor. so if you're telling me I have them when coding typescript normally there has to be a way to configure a blazor project so I can also use them.

Comment: @looat try installing the [typescript msbuild package](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/type-script-with-blazor). I've never tried it, generally you are using Blazor to avoid using much JavaScript